# In Godot 4.0 is there a way to detect only collisions that happen on the horizontal axis with move_and_collid function?

Tags: game-development, godot

In a platformer game built in godot, this is how I would go about making an enemy move autonomously from side to side (meaning he will walk up to a wall, collide with it, and turn around.

```
extends CharacterBody3D

var speed = 0.1
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/3d/default_gravity")
func _physics_process(delta):

    if !is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = gravity

    velocity.x = speed
        #collided is a boolean representing whether or not the character collided with a body or not
    var collided = move_and_collide(velocity)
    if collided:
        speed *= -1
```

However, A problem arises with this code. since I have gravity which moves the enemy downwards the enemy collides with the floor, causing the `collided` boolean to return true. Which causes the enemy to turn around rapidly, keeping him in place.

**A solution** I thought of is distinguishing between colliding with the floor and a wall so that I could have the enemy turn around only when colliding with a wall. However I am not sure how to do this. I am also wondering whether or not there is a better and easier to implement solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With `move_and_slide`

*There was here an answer by "user22159971" suggesting to use `move_and_slide` and `is_on_wall`, which is a good idea. However the explanation provided was for Godot 3. And "user22159971" removed the answer instead of updating it.*

In Godot 3 you would have used `move_and_slide` in a `KinematicBody` like this:

```
move_and_slide(velocity, up_direction)
```

In Godot 4 you need to set the `velocity` and `up_direction` properties of the `CharacterBody3D` like this:

```
velocity = something # you are already working with velocity, so keep that
up_direction = something_else # probably Vector3.UP
move_and_slide()
```

In either case, you could then check `is_on_wall` to know if the body collided with a wall (or `is_on_floor` or `is_on_ceiling` to check for floor or ceiling repsectively):

```
if is_on_wall():
    # it is a wall
    pass
```

---

### With `move_and_collide`

Currently you are using `move_and_collide`. Perhaps you want to continue using that.

---

**Multiply by `delta`**

First of all, the method `move_and_collide` does not multiply internally by `delta`, so use it like this:

```
move_and_collide(velocity * delta)
```

*Since `delta` is less than `1.0` (or you have bigger problems), this will result in the body moving slower than it did, so you might want to increase the `velocity` to compensate.*

---

**Get the returned `KinematicCollision3D`**

The method `move_and_collide` returns a `KinematicCollision3D` or `null` if it didn't collide. *It does not return a boolean.*

Actually this code:

```
var collided = move_and_collide(velocity * delta)
if collided:
    speed *= -1
```

Is equivalent to this code:

```
var collided:KinematicCollision3D = move_and_collide(velocity * delta)
if collided != null:
    speed *= -1
```

I bring this up, because you could look into the properties of the `KinematicCollision3D` to get more information, in particular the normal would allow you to distinguish if the body collided with a wall (or floor or ceiling):

```
var collision := move_and_collide(velocity * delta)
if collision == null:
    # did not collide
    pass
else:
    var normal := collision.get_normal()
    var angle := mormal.angle_to(Vector3.UP) # or whatever up you are using
    if angle < floor_max_angle:
        # it is a floor
        pass
    elif angle > (PI - floor_max_angle):
        # it is a ceiling
        pass
    else:
        # it is a wall
        pass
```

---

**Handle multiple collisions**

I should further point out that obviously the body might have collided with multiple things. The last parameter of `move_and_collide` allows you to tell Godot how many collisions to get. It is `1` by default. We can change that:

```
var collisions := move_and_collide(velocity * delta, false, 0.001, false, 32)
```

Here we are telling it to:

- Move `velocity * delta` distance.
- Actually move (`false` here means to not do a simulation test).
- With a safe margin of `0.001` (this is an extra margin distance for the collision, `0.001` is the default).
- Don't do report collisions from the recovery from collision (when the physics engine detects that the body intersects another, it will push it out. That is the recovery. And it might result in it colliding with something else. `false` here means we don't want to get those in the result).
- And report up to `32` collisions (the thing we actually wanted to change, again `1` is the default).

Now, we can iterate over the collisions:

```
var collisions := move_and_collide(velocity * delta, false, 0.001, false, 32)
if collisions == null:
    # did not collide
    pass
else:
    for index in collisions.get_collision_count():
        var normal := collision.get_normal(index)
        var angle := mormal.angle_to(Vector3.UP) # or whatever up you are using
        if angle < floor_max_angle:
            # it is a floor
            pass
        elif angle > (PI - floor_max_angle):
            # it is a ceiling
            pass
        else:
            # it is a wall
            pass
```